# Qlik Sense: How to concatenate

Tags: qliksense

I want to concatenate (I think) two datasets, but I'm not quite sure how it should be done given that they differ in form.

```
Action:
Qualify *;
sql exec [StoredProcedure];

ProcessStep:
Qualify *;
SELECT distinct
    MRN = pat.CPR_PatientId
    , pt.ProcessTaskId
    , pts.ProcessTaskStepId
    , pts.CreatedDTM
    , tsd.Name
FROM Table A
inner join Table B on A.column1= B.column1;
```

So what I want to do is link these two datasets (Action and ProcessStep) together on one column (ProcessTaskId) so that way when I use a filter on one sheet, it will affect both tables that are displayed on that sheet. But where I'm getting confused is how the syntax should be done. I tried doing a `LOAD Resident Action concatenate ProcessStep on...` etc but that doesn't take. How would I go about this?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are using `Qualify *` on both tables?

Comment: To keep the data segregated. I believe I just got this sorted out. I added an Unqualify ProcessTaskId and that seems to have worked. One filter affects both tables now.

Comment: Yep. Thats the way :)